# VS Code does not see files when a global path is used in the import statement

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, import, intellisense

VS Code does not see files when a global path is used in the import statement. How could I fix it?

[image]

When I try to use a path from the top level it works fine in my app, but VS Code does not like the path. And hence the VS Code does not provide any Intellisense for the types imported using such a path. And I need the Intellisense.

E.g. if I import the `bar` inside the file `app/foofolder/fooimporter.ts` using the following statement:

```
import { bar } from './../bar';
```

VS Code likes it and the Intellisense works just fine.

But when I try to do the following:

```
import { bar } from 'app/bar';
```

The VS Code tells me:

> Cannot find module 'app/bar' or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307)

While in both the cases app functionality is fine and the `bar` is imported okay.

I am working with Angular and typescript (maybe it makes any difference).

Comment: In `tsconfig.json`, you need to specify a `"baseUrl"` under `"compilerOptions"`

Comment: @AluanHaddad, for me it is empty (i.e. compilerOptions.baseUrl === ""). What should I change it to?

Comment: @AluanHaddad, ok. I just have tried putting the dot (i.e. compilerOptions.baseUrl === ".") and it did not help. Also I have tried the compilerOptions.baseUrl === "./".

Comment: @AluanHaddad, oh. Lol. I have figured out the issue. It was that I opened with VS Code a different folder. `../appGrandParent/appParent/app/..` - once I open the `appGrandParent` with the VS Code the question issue is fixed, while I was opening the `appParent`. Should I remove the question or will you post an answer?

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer. There is already a lot on this topic